# how to use Yii Eselect2 to save more data?

Tags: php, yii, selection, yii-extensions

I use [Eselect2 Yii extension](https://github.com/anggiaj/ESelect2) to give users multiple choice but only last choice is submitted via POST. Why?

This is my html, in which I also tried to manage all choices with array but without success

```
<pre>echo $form->labelEx($model,'city_id');
    $this->widget('ext.select2.ESelect2', array(
        'name' => 'Form[field]',
        'data' => City::model()->getCitie`enter code here`s(),
        'options' => array('width' => '30%','allowClear'=>true),
        'htmlOptions'=>array(                       
            'options'=>array(''=>array('value'=>null,'selected'=>null, 'name'=>'field'),),
            'multiple'=>'multiple',
        )
    ));
</pre>
```

I tried to specify 'name' field as single field and as an array but I have the same problem: only last value is sended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should simply use an array :

Instead of

```
    'name' => 'Form[field]',
```

You should try :

```
    'name' => 'Form[field][]',
```